# Firebase database with android studio not adding to db correctly

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating this app in android which I have connected to Firebase Auth and Fireabase Database. Below I will post the code. I'm able to auntheticate user and when I try to add to the database it works for each user but only one field.

For example: in my app I have a user and i want to add a child called save location and set the value to the address that is clicked by the user and it works but when i try to save another address it overrides my current address in the database. Its only letting me add one thing... This onclick event is triggered when a user clicks a save button I have on the app.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id)
      {
          FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();

       if (firebaseUser != null){
               myRef.child("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid().toString()).child("Saved Location").setValue(getSelectedItemOfList);

         } else{
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This feature for only registered Users",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

      }
```

Comment: use push method for this

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line

```
myRef.child("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid().toString()).child("Saved Location").setValue(getSelectedItemOfList);
```

with this:

```
DatabaseReference myRef1 = database.getReference();    

myRef1= myRef.child("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid().toString()).child("Saved Location");

myRef1.push().setValue(getSelectedItemOfList);
```

Comment: @rjimenez52 check updated answer if you didn't solve your issue just share us your firbase json format.

Comment: perfect that worked! Thanks so much Waleed. Question: how come separated like that worked but when I put it all together in one line it didn't work?

Comment: first of all if its resolve your issue kindly marked as solution and up vote it 

explanation:
When you set put before set value. like attached with database ref. it will call the once and make the reference. when you set push in set value. it will trigger whenever you set value.